# Saving NSDictionary from json result to NSUserDefaults return "attempt to insert non-property list object" error

Tags: ios, objective-c

hello i have json data like this

result from NSLog(@"JSON sec blnce list: %@", responseObject);:

```
{
detail =     (
            {
        account = 9X000101300160;
        balance = "1.000.000";
        date = "<null>";
        price = 0;
        secCode = 9999;
        type = Blocked;
        value = 0;
    },
            {
        account = 9X000101300160;
        balance = "1.000.000";
        date = "<null>";
        price = 0;
        secCode = 9999;
        type = Available;
        value = 0;
    }
);
header =     {
    date = 24092012;
    investorID = IDD010239865303;
    securityType = Equity;
};
}
```

what i want to do is saving this json result into NSUserDefaults. Here is how i save:
in .h

```
@property NSDictionary *jsonResult;
```

in .m

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        [manager POST:URI_SECURITY_BALANCE_DETAIL parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];


            NSLog(@"JSON sec blnce list: %@", responseObject);

            self.jsonResult = responseObject;

            //simpan hasil query ke device
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:self.jsonResult forKey:@"securityBalanceNextJsonResult"];
            [defaults synchronize];
```

but above code give me an error: "Attempt to set a non-property-list object"

how i save NSDictionary that i got from json result into NSUserDefaults??

update:(solved)
may be someone have the same problems, here is how my working code:

```
self.jsonResult = responseObject;

        NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.jsonResult options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"securitiesBalanceJsonResult"];

        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* jsonDB = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:[defaults objectForKey:@"securitiesBalanceJsonResult"]

                              options:kNilOptions 
                              error:&error];

        NSLog(@"data:%@",jsonDB);
```

Comment: What does  NSLog(@"JSON sec blnce list: %@", responseObject); print?

Comment: its print json data i mention on first paragraph
JSON sec blnce list:{
detail =     (
            {
        account = 9X000101300160;
        balance = "1.000.000";
        date = "<null>";
        price = 0;
        secCode = 9999;
        type = Blocked;
        value = 0;
    },
            {
        account = 9X000101300160;
        balance = "1.000.000";
        date = "<null>";
        price = 0;
        secCode = 9999;
        type = Available;
        value = 0;
    }
);
header =     {
    date = 24092012;
    investorID = IDD010239865303;
    securityType = Equity;
};
}

Comment: you should make a proper model object from your response then store it in nsuserdefault after converting it to nsdata.

Comment: @pawan: seems right to me since it'd better to construct a model and easy to store and retrieve info.

Comment: @NhonNguyen correct, now you are on right track. if you need any help, tell me here. good luck!!

Comment: @pawan: thanks for the proposition but it's not me who posed the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only explanation I can think of is that your server is sending you nulls inside the JSON. When the result is converted to an `NSDictionary`, instances of `NSNull` are inserted to the dictionary to represent those nulls.

However, `NSNull`is not a property value, that's why you're not being able to store your dictionary on the user defaults. As the [NSUserDefaults documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html) states:

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

You have two options:

1. Remove the keys with nulls (in the example, both `date`s in `detail`).
2. Save the dictionary as a `NSData`.

For the first:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutable = [dictionary mutableCopy];
NSArray *array = mutable[@"detail"];
NSMutableArray *mut = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];
for (NSDictionary *d in array)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *m = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *k in d) {
        id v = d[k];
        if (![v isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            m[k] = v;
        }
    }
    [mut addObject:m];
}
mutable[@"detail"] = mut;
```

For the second:

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:key];
```

Comment: "<null>" is a string, not NSNull. Don't you think so?

Comment: "<null>" is what an NSNull instance returns as its description. If you log an NSNull, that's what you'll get in the console.

Comment: I don't think so cause as you see, the json is retrieved by calling a webservice. And "<null>" is returned by the server as a string inside a json structure.

Comment: yeah you were right "<null>" is what make it error. i got no error when changing the null value in my testing app. but the problem is in my real app i can't change that null value because i receive that from server. i'll try the second option and updated here if it success

Comment: i'm successfully save the result as nsdata, here is my code:
self.jsonResult = responseObject;
            
            NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.jsonResult options:kNilOptions error:nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"securitiesBalanceJsonResult"];
            
            
            NSLog(@"data:%@",(NSDictionary *)[defaults objectForKey:@"securitiesBalanceJsonResult"]);
but how i call it as NSDictionary? nslog above give me nsdata formated result

Comment: successfully save and called the json result.. i'll update it on first thread

Comment: @Herahadi Note that the code serves only as an example. You should be careful using NSJSONSerialization, it may not convert your dictionary to data. If you're not sure that what is contained be the dictionary is always compatible with NSJSONSerialization, you should check for errors. Take a look a [NSJSONSerialization documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @NhonNguyen Because the title refers to saving NSDictionary and the log is not a valid JSON, but a 
similar result of a print of a dictionary, I deduced `responseObject` was an NSDictionary. Knowing that NSNull instances can't be saved to the user defaults, I concluded that the most reasonable explanation (if not the only) was that "<null>" was not a string but the description of an NSNull. I've updated the answer to clarify that a bit.